# Kalman filter: Understanding the derivation of the Covariance Matrix update

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control, kalman-filter

I am looking at some [tutorials](https://medium.com/@jaems33/understanding-kalman-filters-with-python-2310e87b8f48) on deriving the Kalman Filter. The ideas make sense, except for one thing that I am unclear about--the update to the Covariance matrix. I was hoping someone could validate my intuition for that first term in the Covariance matrix update.

Let me setup the system. I will use the same notation as the tutorial, even though it is not the choice of symbols that I would pick. We are given an initial state $X_0, P_0$, which represent the initial state vector and Covariance matrix. The matrix $A$ is the transition matrix and $B$ is the matrix of controls. $Q_t$ is a disturbance term and $w_t$ is a noise term. The update or prediction represents the updated $X_t, P_t$ as the combination of the previous state of the system and a new measurement.

$$
X_t = AX_{t-1} + Bu_t + w_t \\
P_t = AP_{t-1}A^T + Q_t
$$

What is a little confusing is this $AP_{t-1}A^T$, which looks like what Gil Strang would call a Stiffness Matrix. My real question is why is this update to the convariance matrix formulated as this kind of Stiffness matrix. I always think of $A$ as a first order system of differential equation, it is not clear to me why this generates the Covariance matrix.

My intuition--and please correct me if I am wrong, is that if I just had $A^TA$, then that would give me the covariance matrix for the system states. I had never really thought of a covariance matrix like this before--I come from statistics and we usually think of covariance as correlations between predictors and not system states. So having the $P_{t-1}$ in the middle must in some way adjusts the $A^TA$ by the previous measurements on the covariance of the system. I am not quite clear on

Of course, the other strange thing is that usually in the Stiffness Matrix structure $A^TCA$, the inner matrix $C$ is usually diagonal right?

Comment: If $Y=AX$, what is the covariance of $Y$?

Comment: @brian oh yes you mean the measurement vector right. Good question. The tutorial did not address that, so I imagine that there is no measurement error. But you are absolutely right. I imagine that there is a covariance matrix for the  measurements. And then this will feed back to the covariance matrix for the actual state vector.

Comment: But I imagine the same $A^TPA$ is in effect even in that case right.

Comment: You should know that the covariance of $Y=AX$ is $A \mbox{cov}(X)A^{T}$.

Comment: @BrianBorchers Ahh, very good. Yes, this is very helpful. At least I know I am on the right track here. There are just so many tutorials and notations for the Kalman that it is hard to figure out the simple story through the notation. But yes, you have validated some of my intuition here. Very helpful, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work it out from the definition, i.e.

$$\begin{align}
P_t &= E[(x_t-\hat{x}_t)(x_t-\hat{x}_t)^T] \\
&= E[(A x_{t-1} + B u_t + w_t - A \hat{x}_{t-1} + B u_t)(A x_{t-1} + B u_t + w_t - A \hat{x}_{t-1} + B u_t)^T] \\
&= E[(A (x_{t-1} - \hat{x}_{t-1}) + w_t)(A (x_{t-1} - \hat{x}_{t-1}) + w_t)^T] \\
&= A E[(x_{t-1} - \hat{x}_{t-1}) (x_{t-1} - \hat{x}_{t-1})^T] A^T + E[w_t w_t^T] \\
&= A P_{t-1} A^T + Q_t \\
\end{align}$$

This of course uses the assumption that $x_t$ and $w_t$ are independent processes.

Comment: yes, this makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to derive it. It fits with what Brian Borchers said above. This is not so bad once you laid it out. There are so many different tutorials and notations for this same filter, that I was having trouble sorting out the noise myself ;) .